# Is it possible to access ServletContext from portlet code?

Tags: java, servlets, liferay, portlet

Is it possible to obtain `ServletContext` from `MyPortlet extends MVCPortlet` in Liferay? I know SC can be obtained from companion JSP, but I wonder if it is possible to access this object from the portlet class itself?

**EDIT**

There is `PortalUtil.getServletContext()` method, but it is strange since it is not only returns SC, but also takes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to get the `HttpServletRequest` and get it from there:

```
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);
ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
```

Comment: btw if you can go for spring-portlet-mvc instead of vendor-dependent solutions. IMO it's easily the most complete portlet framework out there.